# R - Find if student followed courses or stopped (dplyr)

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

```
Student <- c("A","A","A","A","B", "B", "B")
Course <- c("Course_A","Course_B","Course_C", "Course_F", "Course_A", "Course_D", "Course_E")
Date_Started <- c('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-01-01', "2018-05-01", '2018-09-01')
df <- data.frame(Student, Course, Date_Started)

df$Date_Started<- as.Date(df$Date_Started, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

I want to summarize the data in a way that I can find:

- what course a student started with
- If a stop happened (which is when there are > 3 months inbetween the start dates of courses)
- If a student continued another course after stopping

The table that I would like to end up with is:
[image]

So I tried different things with dplyr. I get to the first part with something like this:

```
df$Date_Started<- as.Date(df$Date_Started, format="%Y-%m-%d")

df_s_test<-df %>% 
  group_by(Student) %>% 
  mutate(CheckDate = ymd(`Date_Started`),
         Diff_Months = abs((interval(CheckDate, lag(CheckDate, 
                                                    default = first(CheckDate))) %/% 
                              months(1)))) %>% 
  summarise(First_Course = first(Course),
            LastCourseBeforeStop = last(Course[Diff_Months <= 3]))
```

Which gives me the following output of the example:

```
df_s_test
  Student First_Course LastCourseBeforeStop        
   A       Course_A     Course_B            
   B       Course_A     Course_A
```

But this is just a small part of what I want. I get in trouble when I want it to look after the `LastCourseBeforeStop` for the `CourseContinuedAfterStop`. Could someone help me on completing what I would like to get as a result?

Comment: Can you put the output of `dput(df)`

Comment: @Julien Yes I added the example with output now in my question :) It's basically that I don't know how to setup with dplyr: how to look per student at each following row, comparing it to the row previous (ordered by date) and see if there was a gap longer then 3 months..

Comment: Can you contact me on Telegram `@julauto`, so we can talk more easily ?

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if the following code solves a part of your problem correctly

```r
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  group_by(Student) %>% 
  mutate(
    CheckDate = ymd(`Date_Started`),
    Diff_Date = abs(interval(CheckDate, lag(CheckDate, default = first(CheckDate))))) %>% 
  summarise(
    First_Course = first(Course),
    LastCourseBeforeStop = last(Course[-1][Diff_Date[-1] <= months(3)]) %>% replace_na("Not Followed"),
    LastCourseBeforeStop_Date = last(CheckDate[-1][Diff_Date[-1] <= months(3)]),
    Continued = if_else(First_Course == LastCourseBeforeStop | First_Course == "Not Followed","No", "Yes"))
```